# Multiple case merge sql

Tags: sql, merge, sas

I have two datasets `a` and `b` each with fields for cusip and ticker. The **sql** i'd like to perform would take `a` column from set `b` `if a.cusip=b.cusip`, but if i cannot find a match for the cusip, i'd like to take the column from `b` `if a.ticker=b.ticker`.

Is there an easy way to execute this?  I'm having trouble constructing the code in one go.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: DID THE BELOW ANSWER YOUR QUESTION @Ryan Lewis

Comment: Sorry to leave everyone hanging.  Seems like all the solutions are valid, but NullSoul i think is the most elegant.  I can think of additional uses for the case one though!

Comment: @Ryan Lewis  glad it worked for you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner join and Or in your where Clause condition should do the job.

```
Select *     from a 
inner join   b on a.cusip=b.cusip 
or           a.ticket = b.ticket;
```

Comment: "Inner Join" will retrieve (only) matching data from both tables and "OR" will satisfy your condition on either match cusip OR tickets.

Comment: Just a quick comment on this solution: while it works and is elegant in terms of code, it seems to take a while on a big dataset (12gb.)  I have yet to compare this to other options but for some reason its a bit slower than doing each ticker and cusip query seperately, then joining and excluding duplicates.

Comment: Yes `OR` statements are very difficult for databases to optimize so they generally have poor performance.  If efficiency is more important than readability your best bet may be to avoid them.

Comment: @Ryan Lewis I did not know about the size of your table. Yes, as Rob Mentioned the cost of the operation for "OR" is very expensive.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to join to your B table twice, once on cusip and once on ticker.  Then you can use `coalesce` to take the first non-null value.

```
select
coalesce (b_cusip.column, b_ticker.column),
...

    from
    a
    left outer join b b_cusip
      on a.cusip = b_cusip.cusip
    left outer join b b_ticker
      on a.ticker = b_ticker.ticker
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
data dataset_a;
input cusip ticker;
datalines;
1 111
2 222
3 333
5 555
;
run;
data dataset_b;
input cusip ticker value;
datalines;
1 111 10
20 222 25
30 333 40
4 444 55
;
run;

proc sql _method;
create table mydata as 
select 
a.*
,b.value
from dataset_a as a
left join dataset_b as b
on (case     
        when a.cusip=b.cusip then 1
        when a.ticker=b.ticker then 1
        else 0
    end)=1
;
quit;
```

returns:

```
cusip    ticker    value
1   111   10
2   222   25
3   333   40
5   555    .
```